# Pass kernel and boot logs to syslog

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog

I have a systemd based system and for some services I had to set up remote logging. The simplest way to set this was to use `rsyslog` and set the 
`StandardOutput=syslog` in the unit file.

Now I also need the boot messages and kernel logs remotely logged, but can't locate a unit file representing the kernel where I would put `StandardOutput=syslog`.

Any ideas on how to approach that?

Answer (score 2):

Systemd uses *journald* to do logging. It is configured in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. See `man journald.conf`. In particular you can create the file `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/my.conf` with the contents

```
ForwardToSyslog=on
```

to have all logging sent to socket `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`. Normally, `syslog` is configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to read this socket by having at its start the line

```
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
```

You can use the usual syslog filtering on this data stream.

Comment: Hey, was asking on the peculiarities on setting the kernel logging in journald and how it differs from setting logging for a system service (because the kernel can't really have a unit file).

Comment: Note, if you want to get the messages from the kernel as they are printed on the console, you can have the kernel send them over udp using the [netconsole](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole) boot option. If I remember correctly, systemd recovers the dmesg logs from kernel memory as soon as it can, and puts them in a ramfs file, until a real file is available. The kernel only outputs to the console and the dmesg in-memory log.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the logs from the kernel needs a different approach than getting the logs from a service.

Kernel stores it's logs in memory in a structure called the *kernel ring buffer*. This is exposed to userspace through a special file `/dev/kmsg`. [By default](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#ReadKMsg=) `journald` will read that file. So if journald is forwarding everything to rsyslog it will forward the kernel messages too.